# ERC20 coin fees

Tags: ether, erc-20, tokens

If I want to issue a coin based on ETH blockchain (let's call it BBB coin) which called smart contract or ERC20, my question is about the fees.

is the fee for every transaction of BBB coin will be by ETH or BBB? and how I can control the fees amount when I make the coin by MINT software?

as I saw that many exchangers that accept coins based on ERC20 they didn't deduct any ETH fees for transferring erc20' coins.

thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gas fees is always paid in ETHER.

Now for user(User is sending tokens)-
The gas fees is AUTO-REFILLED continuously to the minimum limit of ETHER that will be required for transactions of tokens. This is handled by smart contract without exposing it to user. This is one implementation to hide gas refill from user. You can check more details here - https://ethereum.org/token

Now for exchanges(User is sending tokens from exchange wallet)-
The gas fees and exchange commission is paid from the amount you are transferring.
i.e. You are transferring 10 BBB tokens, then actual amount received by receiver will be like 9.10 BBB.(Less than 10 BBB)

Answer (score 0):

The gas fee is always paid in Ether and not your token. The exchange takes care of the gas fee in Ether from the trading fee you pay.